# How to enable IIS native modules for third party application

Tags: ruby, powershell-5.0, iis-modules

## Background-

We have installed a 3rd party application over the web server. This application would run seamlessly only when we enable specific modules list in 'Configure Native Modules' action over the IIS. The installation is done silently and it does list the required modules however we have to enable them manually.

## Ask-

We are trying to figure out if there is any way we can enable the required modules using powershell or ruby script. This will enable us to do the needful without manual intervention.

We have tried to incorporate approach suggested in the below blog. However, we didn't got the desired outcome.

Blog-
https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/may/25/automating-iis-feature-installation-with-powershell

Comment: _We have tried to incorporate approach suggested in the below blog. However, we didn't got the desired outcome._ What **exactly** did you do and what **exactly** was the outcome and what **exactly** did not work? Be specific and include these details in your post.

Comment: Sure and apologies as I didn't add this piece of info in my post.
Here is what I have tried- the blog suggests to use the command-
 Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online | where FeatureName -like 'IIS-*'
to discover the list of all IIS feature.

& we are looking for a 3rd party feature. Even though we have tried to modify the command we did not get the required feature.Command we have used-

Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process
#Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online | where FeatureName -like 'IIS-*'
Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online | where {$_.state -eq "Enabled"} | ft -Property